# Calculate percentage within a subgroup in R

Tags: r, grouping, percentage

I am new to R and I am struggling with calculating the percentage of certain observations in a data frame. My data frame is coming from an excel table with many rows and columns. Therefore, I first need to create a query of the information I need. I use the following code to do so:

```
am2 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  count(motif)
```

The output looks like this:

```
country     motif                        number
------------------------------------------------
Portugal    architectural elements        26        
Portugal    blossom                        3        
Portugal    crescent moon                 28        
Portugal    crosses                        5        
Portugal    floral                         3        
Spain       four-legged animal            14        
Spain       herringbone                    2        
Spain       horseman                       2        
Sweden      human                          1        
Sweden      inscription                  147
Sweden      spiral                        44
```

I also calculated the total number of observations per country from the original data frame like this:

```
am2 %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarize("Number of Observations" = n())
```

This is the output:

```
country            total number motifs
----------------------------------------
Portugal                  536
Spain                     2110
Sweden                    300
```

Now I would like to calculate the frequency of each motif per country. If I would do it by hand it would be e.g. the number of the motif "architectural element" occuring in Portugal:

```
26/536*100
```

So, whenever the country changes, the total number for the motifs and thus for the percentage calculation changes. I don't know how to automate this process. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first group by country to get the sum for each country. Then you group by country and motiv and use the sum for each country to calculate your frequency.

```
 am2 %>%
      group_by(country) %>%
      mutate(sum_country = sum(number)) %>% 
      group_by(country, motif) %>% 
      mutate(freq = number/sum_country,
             freq_perc = freq*100 %>% round(2))
```

`ggplot2` example:

```
df <- am2 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(sum_country = sum(number)) %>% 
  group_by(country, motif) %>% 
  mutate(freq = number/sum_country,
         freq_perc = freq*100 %>% round(2))

library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x=country, y=freq_perc, fill=motif)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I get the following error:
Error in mutate(., sum_country = sum(country)) : 
i The error occurred in group 1: country = "Portugal".
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: It has to be `sum(number)`of course. Sorry! I edited in the code.

Comment: Amazing, it works! Thanks a lot!! Do you also know how to show the frequency in actual percentage numbers. I.e. multiplied by 100.  I guess I could have the entire column multiplied by 100 but maybe theres a way to already include it in the code you wrote.

Comment: I edited it to include a column, you can also do it in the same line of code, i.e. `freq = number/sum_country*100)`

Comment: After a while, I used this code again on a different data frame. For some reason it does calculate the percentage but it does not round off to two digits but keeps ten digits. I do not get an error code, however. I don't know what the problem is. Could it have to do with the format? It says double in my dataframe.

Comment: hmm, does manually rounding work, e.g`round(am2$freq_perc,2)`?

Comment: It does when I only run the code I get the right result in a single line. But when I want to see the dataframe it still shows the many digits like before. I need to have it in my dataframe to continue using it for a barplot.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the assignment e.g. you need to assign `<-` the transformed data to an object to use for instance further in a barplot, e.g. `am2 <- am2 %>%
      group_by(country) %>%
      mutate(sum_country = sum(number)) %>% 
      group_by(country, motif) %>% 
      mutate(freq = number/sum_country,
             freq_perc = freq*100 %>% round(2))`

Comment: No, I double checked everything. And the code works, I do not get an error. But the numbers still show all the digits. If I do it manually with this code: 
round(aa4$freq_perc,2)
it works, but when I continue, trying to make a barplot showing the rounded percentages, it still shows all the digits.

Comment: I added a ggplot example, where your problem does not show up, though. Alternatively, you could use the `scales::percent` function to round inside your ggplot.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the `scales::percent` function and it gives me an error saying **non-numeric argument to binary operator**